# Uppercase column names from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Have an external MYSQL DB and I am connecting it to the ruby app. All the columns are changes to uppercase and when I try to query something it works but ruby gives an `undefined method` error when i try to call some field from the object like:

`user = User.first` works but when i do `user.firstname` it says `undefined method firstname` because the user object I get has firstname column as `FIRSTNAME`. How can I make it a case-incentive query so either i do `user.firstname` or `user.FIRSTNAME` it works?

i tried adding `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true` into my `cofig/initializers/activereport_sqlserver_adapter.rb` but still no change.

Comment: You are using the mysql-adapter not sqlserver. Your lowercase config is not for mysql.

Comment: @OliverGaida i am not able to find any reference where i can do this globally! 
How do you do this for MYSQL?

Comment: Like how do you set it up for MYSQL

Comment: I have plan, i only wanted say that it is a different adapter.